# why am i getting typemismatch error in phaser project, i am using internet explorer 10 to deploy the game?

Tags: html5-canvas, phaser-framework

When ever i click a button to re-draw my level state i am getting following error `this.__tilePattern=c.createPattern(this.tilingTexture.baseTexture.source,"repeat")`, how to resolve this ? , is it related to canvas rendering or tilesprite rendering?

Comment: What exactly does that button call?

Comment: it is used to change from `state a` to `state b` , if i disable tilesprites everything is fine, i can't understand what's the problem when tilesprites are included.

Comment: Are the tileSprites properly preloaded for the second state?

Comment: The first state is reloaded again after the button click, it's not any other state, i am using this to reload a state again `this.state.start('main',true);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange to say but now my problem is vanished completely when i used older version of `phaser 2.2.2` rather than new updated version `2.3.0`, it would be great if photonstorm can explain what caused this error when new version is used.